# MySQL order of joined rows?

Tags: mysql, join

I have two tables:

Table `orders` holds all the orders for all customers (simplified):

```
Field       Type             Null    Key    Default Extra
==================================================================
id          int(11)          NO      PRI    NULL    auto_increment  
customerId  int(11)          NO      PRI    NULL    
...
```

There is an unique index on `(customerId, id)`.

Table `customerindex` holds information about the customers (simplified):

```
Field       Type             Null    Key    Default Extra
=========================================================
customerId  int(11)          NO      PRI    NULL    
name        varchar(64)      NO      MUL    NULL    
...
```

There is a fulltext index on `name`

Now i want to seach for customers by their names (using the fulltext index) and list their orders.

What i basically need is something like this:

```
customerX     order5
customerX     order4
...
customerY     order6
customerY     order5
...
```

For each customer I want the orders orderd by their id but **the order of the customers itself does not matter**.

What i do is

```
SELECT ...
FROM `customerindex` AS `idx`
LEFT JOIN `orders` ON (`orders`.`id` = `idx`.`id`)
WHERE MATCH ... AGAINST ...
ORDER BY `orders`.`customerId`, `orders`.`id` DESC
```

But of course this needs `filesort`.

If I only want the orders for one customer and want to sort them by the order id this is possible without filesort.

**So the question is:** Is it somehow possible (maybe correlated subqueries?) to get the outlined resultset without the need for filesort? (i.e. influence the order of the joined orders independent of fields from the table they are joined to)

Comment: The only (really: the only) way to guarantee any ordering is an `order by`. Any "order" you see without an `order by` is pure coincidence and can (and probably will) change anytime.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to guarantee ordering in MySQL is by using `order by` or `group by`.

Your question is really:  Is there a way to defined indexes on my table to avoid the `filesort`?

If you have a `where` clause that explicitly chooses one customer, and you have an index on `orders(customerid, orderid)`, then you might have some luck.  The query plan you are looking for is a scan on the `orders` index, with the filter applying row by row from the index.  Such a query plan seems theoretically possible, the question is how to get MySQL to use it.

Comment: thanks, especially the last part of your answer is exactly what i had in mind